# What is the proper way to benchmarking a simple PHP-MySQL website with automated test cases

Tags: page-load-time

I am a novice in the area of benchmarking and so would like to request for your guidance.

**Problem:** I have a test website developed in PHP and MySQL hosted in the localhost.

I need to perform the following set of activities:-

1. Login as a registered user
2. Download a PDF file

*I wish to know how to load test the above activities in order? I need to check if at a particular instant, 'n' number of users are logged in and they download a pdf file, what would be the worst response time and related stats.*

**Steps I already did** (Please correct me if I did something wrong here.):-

1. Used the apache benchmarking tool (ab) to load test the login authentication script page passing the username and password as parameters

> (i.e., ab -n 1000 -c 100 -A username:password url_of_script.php)

1. I tested both for apache and nginx webservers (got comparatively better results in nginx)
2. But, I want to test if after login, the user performs some other activities, how can we use the ab (or some other) tool to assess the load.

Waiting for your responses. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a PHP script using curl.

Use your Browser to login and and downlaod the PDF.

Before you do that, right click and select Inspect or Inspect Element.  Go to the Network tab. Then start the login and download PDF process.

In the Network Tab look only at the request headers of each HTML page request. Filter out all the other requests (e.g. JS CSS images, media and etc.).  You can use these headers as a guideline when setting up curl to do each request.

In FireFox you can edit the headers and resend.  Go in to the edit mode and copy the request header.

In your curl requests use exactly the the same request the Browser used.

Curl reports all the stats on the request and response.